# Visitor pattern with multiple visit implementations

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to do various operation over a Composition pattern. I vas these implementation of the Visitor Pattern with the Composite Pattern.

Interface:

```
public interface Visitor {
    void visit(DayPart dayPart);
    void visit(DayParting dayParting);
    void visit(TimePart timePart);
}
```

The visitor method in the Composite Class:

```
public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
        Iterator<AbstractComposite> itr = iterator();
        Parting children;
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            children = (Parting) itr.next();
            children.accept(visitor);
        }
    }
```

The visitor method over the leaf:

```
@Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
```

The visitor Class implementation:

```
public class myVisitor implements Visitor {
    @Override
    public void visit(DayPart dayPart) {
        //do something (or not)
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(DayParting dayParting){
        // do something (or not)
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(TimePart timePart){
        //do something (or not)
    }
}
```

The problem is that i need do various operations over the Composition and with this design i need to do a new class for every "visit" what i need to do and this is pretty impractical.

So, i was thinking do something like this (i put generic names) with inners classes.

```
public abstract class VisitorImpl implements Visitor {
    //Hook methods
    @Override
    public void visit(Composite composite) {
        //hok method
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Composite2  composite2) {
        //hook method
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Leaf leaf) {
        //hook method
    }

    public static Visitor ParticularVisitor(){
        return new ParticularVisitor();
    }
    private static class ParticularVisitor extends VisitorImpl {
        @Override
        public void visit(Composite composite) {
            //do something real.
        }
        @Override
        public void visit(Composite2 composite2) {
            //do something real.
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(Leaf leaf) {
            //do something real.
        }
    }
    private static class ParticularVisitor_2 extends VisitorImpl {
        public ParticularVisitor_2(){
        }
        @Override
        public void visit(Leaf leaf){
            //Just do something with this
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a good solution to my problem? any improve?

Comment: How does having static nested classes change that you need a visitor implementation per way-of-visiting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ## Visitor Design Pattern
>
> ### Intent
>
> - Represent an operation to be performed on the elements of an object structure.
> - Visitor lets you define a new operation without changing the classes of the elements on which it operates.
> - The classic technique for recovering lost type information.
> - Do the right thing based on the type of two objects.
> - Double dispatch
>
> ### Problem
>
> **Many distinct and unrelated operations need to be performed on node 
>   objects** in a heterogeneous aggregate structure. You want to avoid
>   "polluting" the node classes with these operations. And, you don't want 
>   to have to query the type of each node and cast the pointer to the correct
>   type before performing the desired operation.

From: [Sourcemaking](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor)

So, your "problem"

> "The problem is that i need do various operations over the Composition
>   and with this design i need to do a new class for every "visit" what i
>   need to do and this is pretty impractical."

is not exactly a problem, is how Visitor is supposed to work.

```
One operation to be performed = one visitor
```

If there is no relationship between your operations, that's the best you can do with Visitor.

Comment: Imagine i have two payment types:would it be wrong to do something like this:  public interface IVisitor {

        void visit(StripePaymentStrategy stripePaymentStrategy);
        void visit(BrainTreePaymentStrategy brainTreePaymentStrategy);


        void visitInitialization(StripePaymentStrategy stripePaymentStrategy);
        void visitInitialization(BrainTreePaymentStrategy brainTreePaymentStrategy);

        void visitSomeOtherOperation(StripePaymentStrategy stripePaymentStrategy);
        void visitSomeOtherOperation(BrainTreePaymentStrategy brainTreePaymentStrategy);
    }

Comment: do you think it would be better to just create another visitor since its a different operation of initilization vs visit method ?  where visit(...) would be for  making a payment.